# In the Resolution equivalence ($\neg A \implies B, B \implies C \models \neg A \implies C$) must $A$ be negated?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, propositional-logic

The sheet of equivalences given to us in class provides the the equivalences

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Resolution} & A \vee B, \neg B \vee C \models A \vee C & 
\neg A \implies B, B \implies C \models \neg A \implies C \\ 
\hline
\end{array}

I noticed that the $A$ is negated. **Is this necessary for proper Resolution?** Or is this just an example that $A$ can be negated?

To me it makes logical sense that $A \implies B, B \implies C \models A \implies C$, but being somewhat new to the subject matter I would like to ensure that $\neg A$ is not necessary for Resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes. But the departure point is slightly different.
Here it is:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\neg A \vee B, \neg B \vee C \models \neg A \vee C & 
A \implies B, B \implies C \models A \implies C \\ 
\hline
\end{array}

The former statement is just the fact that if you start with $A\vee B$
and turn it into an implication you find $\neg A\implies B$.

Comment: Ahh so the sheet itself was just trying to be consistent within that example of Resolution, between the left and right sides? // Though by "The answer is yes" you mean in the example I have, I guess my exact question was "For every usage of Resolution must the $A$ be negated"?

Comment: Both are correct, it depends just from the departure assumptions.

Comment: Thank you! Makes sense I think! If you'd like to answer another question, I have another subject matter related question (http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/70828/what-does-the-structure-s-tx-p-in-this-existantial-instantiation-imply-sko)